# CSS overflow:hidden property causes overlapping text

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am trying to hide any overflow that might occur when a guest makes a forum topic post.  In the image below are a list of topics.  I am having trouble with some output overflowing as it should while other output seems to want to cram on top of itself, thwarting my attempts at using overflow:hidden.  The posts with the "W"'s and the "I"'s work fine when overflow:hidden is applied.  But, for example, the post that says "Architects may be the one thing I can think of this time but...." crams on top of itself and overflow hidden has no effect.  Here is the image.  (I'm wonding if this has something to do with the fact that some posts have punctuation in them?)
[image]

Here is some of my CSS and HTML:

```
#topic-area .topic {
position:relative;
width:998px;
padding-left:12px;
padding-right:12px;
border-bottom:1px dashed;
border-left:1px dashed;
border-right:1px dashed;
}
#topic-area .topic .cutoff {
font-family:courier;
position:relative;
top:0px;
width:500px;
height:60px;
float:left;
border:1px solid;
}
#topic-area .topic h3 {
float:left;
display: block;
position:relative;
}
#topic-area .topic a {
display: block;
position:relative;
}
```

```css
#topic-area {
 position:relative;
 top:0px;
 width:1024px;
}
#topic-area #topic-head {
 position:relative;
 width:1024px;
 text-align:center;
 border-bottom:1px dashed;
}
#topic-area #topic-head h2 {
 line-height:0%;
 text-decoration:underline;
}
#topic-area #topic-head a {
 color:black;
 text-decoration:none;
}
#topic-area #topic-head a:hover {
 text-decoration:underline;
}
#topic-area .topic {
 position:relative;
 width:998px;
 padding-left:12px;
 padding-right:12px;
 border-bottom:1px dashed;
 border-left:1px dashed;
 border-right:1px dashed;
}
#topic-area .topic .cutoff {
 font-family:courier;
 position:relative;
 top:0px;
 width:500px;
 height:60px;
 float:left;
 border:1px solid;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#topic-area .topic h3 {
 float:left;
 display: block;
 position:relative;
}
#topic-area .topic a {
 display: block;
 position:relative;
}
#topic-area .topic a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 line-height:0%;
}
#topic-area .topic a:hover {
 text-decoration:underline;
 color:black;
}
#topic-area .topic .started-by {
 
 position:relative;
 color:grey;
 font-size:.8em;
 line-height:0%;
 clear:both;
}
#topic-area .topic .replies-category {
 font-size:.8em;
 line-height:0%;
 color:grey;
 position:relative;
 float:right;
 text-align:right;
}
```

```html
    <div id="topic-area"> 
    <div class="topic">
 <div class="cutoff">
 <h3><a href="#">EXAMPLE TITLE EXAMPLE TEXT EXAMPLE TEXT EXAMPLE TEXT EXAMPLE TEXT</a></h3>
 </div>
    <div class="replies-category">
    <p>Replies: X</p>
    <p>Category: EXAMPLE CATEGORY</p>
    </div>
    <p class="started-by">Started by Xname on Xdate</p>
    </div>
        <div class="topic">
 <div class="cutoff">
 <h3><a href="#">ANOTHER EXAMPLE WHERE TEXT MIGHT RUN OVER OUTSIDE THE BOX..............</a></h3>
 </div>
    <div class="replies-category">
    <p>Replies: X</p>
    <p>Category: EXAMPLE CATEGORY</p>
    </div>
    <p class="started-by">Started by Xname on Xdate</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML instead of the PHP that generates it? The PHP code is irrelevant and makes it hard to try out. It would be extra great if you could use the Code Snippet button `[<>]` and add the HTML and CSS as a runnable code snippet. By the way, there is no `overflow: hidden` at all in your code. Where did you try to add it?

Comment: Where did you set that property "overflow:hidden"? Also, it would be helpful to create jsfiddle and remove irrelevant code parts, highlighting just a problematic one.

Comment: I've tried running overflow:hidden in the h3, but when that didn't work for me I tried to make the "cutoff" class and a div just for using overflow:hidden so if you could see a solution for that, that would be great.  (Will try to make a code snippet now.  Haven't used that before, not sure what it means precisely, but I get what you're saying generally.)  I took overflow:hidden out in my original post just to show how two of the texts were running past the border just fine while two of the other texts got crammed up inside the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, so based on just qualified guess, you may consider using two CSS3 properties applied to the appropriate `HTML` element ( `div`, `h1`, whatsoever):

```
overflow-x:hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Hope this may help. Best regards,

Comment: Hi.  That actually did work.  But I was wondering if there was something that could be done that was acceptable to a wider range of older browsers than just what CSS3 will support?  I don't know if I should check your answer as right and ask about a solution for older browsers in another question, or if the proper thing to do here is edit my question and wait for a response here.  But thanks, this did help a little bit.

Comment: Hi, I am glad it works for you. Please accept the answer if satisfied and should you have more questions, please post them separately. Thanks and regards,